# Nested foreach in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, nested

In my code I have a nested `foreach`, but when run it shows this error [image: Screenshot of error message]

Here is my code:

```
@foreach ($product as $user)

<p>This is title {{ $user->title }}</p>
<p>This is category {{ $user->category }}</p>
<p>This is sub category {{ $user->sub_category }}</p>

@foreach ($product_image as $product_image)
<p>This is image {{ $product_image->p_image }}</p>
@endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

The second foreach sould be:

```
@foreach ($User->product_images as $product_image)
```

an not:

```
@foreach ($product_image as $product_image)
```